# Span background image across 2 table rows but have different background colors

Tags: html, css

Doesn't have to be a table could be div's.

My image has some transparent parts to blend in.  The top part needs to blend with a different background color than the bottom half.

So in my mind would be table with 2 rows one row has one background color and the other has another background color but the image spans over both rows.

Is this possible in HTML/CSS.  This would avoid me cutting the image into two.

Answer (score 0):

Are the image or rows a fixed size? Then you could play with background positioning &/or sizing.

```css
.row {
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/1000/200);
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
.one {
  background-position: top center;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
.two {
  background-position: bottom center;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row one"></div>
<div class="row two"></div>
```

**Or**, logically, though it would probably be easier to wrap the "rows" in a div and put the bg image on that.

```css
.row {
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/1000/200);
  border:1px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  
}

.wrapper {
  background-image: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/1000/200);
  width: 500px;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.wrapper .row {
  background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but what about making row one's background color say red and row two's blue and transparent parts of the image the top would show red and bottom would show blue.

When I tried this myself the cell/row color was on top of the image rather then below the image.

Comment: If your image has transparent parts then in the first example, set a bg color and it will show through. The second option might be a little harder. This was just an example of splitting the image.

Comment: In IE11 setting a background image for the for and then a background color for the cells the image is covered up by the cell's color so that you can't see the image.